# Block filters using fragment shaders

Tags: opengl, shader, glsl, fragment-shader, pixel-shader

I was following [this tutorial](http://www.ozone3d.net/tutorials/image_filtering_p2.php) using Apple's OpenGL Shader Builder (tool similar to Nvidia's fx composer, but simpler).

I could easily apply the filters, but I don't understand if they worked correct (and if so how can I improve the output). For example the blur filter: OpenGL itself does some image processing on the textures, so if they are displayed in a higher resolution than the original image, they are blurred already by OpenGL. Second the blurred part is brighter then the part not processed, I think this does not make sense, since it just takes pixels from the direct neighborhood. This is defined by

```
float step_w = (1.0/width);
```

Which I don't quite understand: The pixels are indexed using floating point values??

[Blurred Image http://img218.imageshack.us/img218/6468/blurzt.png](http://img218.imageshack.us/img218/6468/blurzt.png)

Edit: I forgot to attach the exact code I used:

**Fragment Shader**

```
// Originally taken from: http://www.ozone3d.net/tutorials/image_filtering_p2.php#part_2

#define KERNEL_SIZE 9

float kernel[KERNEL_SIZE];

uniform sampler2D colorMap;
uniform float width;
uniform float height;

float step_w = (1.0/width);
float step_h = (1.0/height);

// float step_w = 20.0;
// float step_h = 20.0;

vec2 offset[KERNEL_SIZE];

void main(void)
{
   int i = 0;
   vec4 sum = vec4(0.0);

   offset[0] = vec2(-step_w, -step_h);  // south west
   offset[1] = vec2(0.0, -step_h);      // south
   offset[2] = vec2(step_w, -step_h);       // south east

   offset[3] = vec2(-step_w, 0.0);      // west
   offset[4] = vec2(0.0, 0.0);          // center
   offset[5] = vec2(step_w, 0.0);       // east

   offset[6] = vec2(-step_w, step_h);       // north west
   offset[7] = vec2(0.0, step_h);       // north
   offset[8] = vec2(step_w, step_h);        // north east


// Gaussian kernel
// 1 2 1
// 2 4 2
// 1 2 1


   kernel[0] = 1.0;     kernel[1] = 2.0;    kernel[2] = 1.0;
   kernel[3] = 2.0; kernel[4] = 4.0;    kernel[5] = 2.0;
   kernel[6] = 1.0;     kernel[7] = 2.0;    kernel[8] = 1.0;


// TODO make grayscale first
// Laplacian Filter
// 0   1   0
// 1  -4   1
// 0   1   0

/*
kernel[0] = 0.0;    kernel[1] = 1.0;    kernel[2] = 0.0;
kernel[3] = 1.0;    kernel[4] = -4.0;   kernel[5] = 1.0;
kernel[6] = 0.0;   kernel[7] = 2.0; kernel[8] = 0.0;
*/

// Mean Filter
// 1  1  1
// 1  1  1
// 1  1  1

/*
kernel[0] = 1.0;    kernel[1] = 1.0;    kernel[2] = 1.0;
kernel[3] = 1.0;    kernel[4] = 1.0;    kernel[5] = 1.0;
kernel[6] = 1.0;   kernel[7] = 1.0; kernel[8] = 1.0;
*/

   if(gl_TexCoord[0].s<0.5)
   {
       // For every pixel sample the neighbor pixels and sum up
       for( i=0; i<KERNEL_SIZE; i++ )
       {
            // select the pixel with the concerning offset
            vec4 tmp = texture2D(colorMap, gl_TexCoord[0].st + offset[i]);
            sum += tmp * kernel[i];
       }

        sum /= 16.0;
   }
   else if( gl_TexCoord[0].s>0.51 )
   {
        sum = texture2D(colorMap, gl_TexCoord[0].xy);
   }
   else // Draw a red line
   {
        sum = vec4(1.0, 0.0, 0.0, 1.0);
   }

   gl_FragColor = sum;
}
```

**Vertex Shader**

```
void main(void)
{
    gl_TexCoord[0] = gl_MultiTexCoord0;
    gl_Position = ftransform();
}
```

Comment: what's the question ? texture coordinates are addressed in the range [0-1], yes.

Answer (score 4):

Texture coordinates conventionally reach from `(0,0)` (bottom left) to `(1,1)` (top right), so in fact, they are floats.

So if you have texturecoordinates `(u,v)`, the "original" coordinates are computed by `(u*textureWidth, v*textureHeight)`.

If the resulting values are not integral numbers, there may be different ways to handle that:

- just take `floor` or `ceil` of the result in order to make the number integral
- interpolate between the neighbouring texels

However I think every shading language has a method to access a texture by their "original", i.e. integral index.

Comment: So then step_w = (1.0/width) should be the numerical distance to the next pixel..

Comment: ugh. This answer has many approximations. 1/ bottom left vs. top right does not mean much to GL. It does not give orientation to textures. 2/ there are no such things as "original" coordinates. There are very good reasons why texture coordinates go from 0 to 1. One of them is mip-mapping. 3/ texels are addressed in their middle...

Comment: Use ARB_texture_rectangle extension.

Answer (score 0):

@Nils, thanks for posting this code. I've been trying to figure out a simple way to do a convolution on the GPU for some time now.
I tried your code out and ran into the same dimming problem myself. Here's how I solved it.

- You have to be careful with your step size to use texture width not
  image width. It usually gets re-sized to a power of 2 when the
  texture is bound in opengl.
- You must also be sure to normalize your
  kernel by summing up all values in your kernel and dividing by that.
- Also it helps if you convolve R G and B separately without the
  illumination, (the fourth component of the sample).

Here's a solution that doesn't have the dimming issue and that also bypasses the need for an offset array for 3x3 kernels .

I've included 8 Kernels that worked for me without dimming.

```
uniform sampler2D colorMap;
uniform float width;
uniform float height;


const mat3 SobelVert= mat3( 1.0, 2.0, 1.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, -1.0, -2.0, -1.0 );
const mat3 SobelHorz= mat3( 1.0, 0.0, -1.0, 2.0, 0.0, -2.0, 1.0, 0.0, -1.0 );
const mat3 SimpleBlur= (1.0/9.0)*mat3( 1.0, 1.0, 1.0, 1.0, 1.0, 1.0, 1.0, 1.0, 1.0 );
const mat3 Sharpen= mat3( 0.0, -1.0, 0.0, -1.0, 5.0, -1.0, 0.0, -1.0, 0.0 );
const mat3 GaussianBlur= (1.0/16.0)*mat3( 1.0, 2.0, 1.0, 2.0, 4.0, 2.0, 1.0, 2.0, 1.0 );
const mat3 SimpleHorzEdge= mat3( 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, -3.0, 3.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0 );
const mat3 SimpleVertEdge= mat3( 0.0, -3.0, 0.0, 0.0, 3.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0 );
const mat3 ClearNone= mat3( 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 1.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0 );

void main(void)
{
   vec4 sum = vec4(0.0);
   if(gl_TexCoord[0].x <0.5)
   {
      mat3 I, R, G, B;
      vec3 sample;

      // fetch the 3x3 neighbourhood and use the RGB vector's length as intensity value
      for (int i=0; i<3; i++){
        for (int j=0; j<3; j++) {
          sample = texture2D(colorMap, gl_TexCoord[0].xy + vec2(i-1,j-1)/vec2(width, height)).rgb;
          I[i][j] = length(sample); //intensity (or illumination)
          R[i][j] = sample.r; 
          G[i][j] = sample.g;
          B[i][j] = sample.b;  
        }
      }

      //apply the kernel convolution
      mat3 convolvedMatR = matrixCompMult( SimpleBlur, R);
      mat3 convolvedMatG = matrixCompMult( SimpleBlur, G);
      mat3 convolvedMatB = matrixCompMult( SimpleBlur, B);
      float convR = 0.0;
      float convG = 0.0;
      float convB = 0.0;
      //sum the result
      for (int i=0; i<3; i++){
        for (int j=0; j<3; j++) {
          convR += convolvedMatR[i][j];
          convG += convolvedMatG[i][j];
          convB += convolvedMatB[i][j];
        }
      }
      sum = vec4(vec3(convR, convG, convB), 1.0);

  }
   else if( gl_TexCoord[0].x >0.51 )
   {
        sum = texture2D(colorMap, gl_TexCoord[0].xy );
   }
   else // Draw a red line
   {
        sum = vec4(1.0, 0.0, 0.0, 1.0);
   }

   gl_FragColor = sum;
}
```